# See encryption versions in sniffed packets (command line)

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, sniffing, tshark

I've sniffed packets with wireshark. There you can see the 'Protocol' (eg TLSv1.2). But if I save this information, this is no longer visible, even if I convert it with tshark. I can search for strings like 'ssl' or 'https', but the protocol is gone.
Any ideas?